# laravel exception Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empt

Tags: laravel

I just want run my proyect, I apply:

```
php artisan serve
```

and I'm getting:

```
In RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php line 41:

  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty
```

why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you erase config folder or some Laravel folder?

Anyway you could try running:

```
composer update
```

OR

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

after you can clear the cache

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

I'm afraid I need more context to help you.

Comment: bro!!! thanks you so much!!! I don't know but I accidentally deleted folder "config"