# RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty

Tags: laravel, vite

I am running my laravel project by applying:

```
php artisan serve
```

and I'm getting:

> In RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php line 41:
> RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty

I tried:

```
composer update
```

but I'm still getting :

> RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): Argument #1 ($directory) cannot be empty
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

What's the problem with this?

I just want to run my laravel project.

I am using Laravel version 10 & Vue(Vite)

Thanks

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280277/laravel-exception-argument-1-directory-cannot-be-empt) help?